# Navicat vs. Toad SSH Tunneling

Tags: mysql, ssh, toad, tunnel, navicat

I am trying to connect to a MySQL server on an AWS instance, using Toad w. SSH.

For reference, I have the following configuration setup in Navicat for MySQL:

General Tab: 
----------
- Connection Name: localhost_3306
- Host Name/IP Address: localhost
- Port : 3306
- Username : xxx
- Password : xxx1
- Save Password: Yes

SSH Tab: 
-----------
- Use SSH Tunnel : Yes
- Host Name/IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (my AWS instance ip)
- Port: 22
- User Name: xxx3
- Authentication Method: Public Key
- Private Key: c:\path_to_my.pem

This works great in Navicat, I can connect to my server and open my db, so no access issues. Question is, how do I setup a similar connection in Toad for MySQL? Do I need to use an external tunnel (e.g. putty) and somehow configure Toad to connect through there, or can I connect directly from Toad?

A complete working example of a similar setup would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this within Toad, simply add a new connection in the "Connection Manager". There you have a "Connection Type" dropdown-menu. Chose "SSH" and fill in required parameters for database and ssh-host. You can distinct those parameters by their prefix "SSH".

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try that. I ended up using putty as ssh tunnel as described here : http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html